# How I can find "Old logs in hive" and from which commands?

Tags: hive

I am unable to find old logs

I am working on CDP cluster and needed a command to find hive old logs of 3 days...

Answer (score 0):

Hiveserver2 and the Hive metastore generate local server logs. You'd SSH to them and run cat/less UNIX commands, probably within /var/log/hive, but that depends on how Hive is installed

Log4j is used for these, and could easily be configured to remove logs older than 3 days, so if that happens, you'll never find them.

To fix this in the future, you should use centralized logging solutions such as Elasticsearch, Grafana Loki, or Splunk.